# Does VS Code have a memory viewer and/or a disassembler for C++ extension?

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-code

I am using Visual Studio Code (VS Code) for debugging my C++ program. I'd like to view the memory at a variable's address and also be able to view the assembly code of my program. I am looking around on VS Code and I am not seeing an option for such views.   I checked around on the marketplace and I don't anything out there.

Not sure if I am not looking in the right place, but do these features exist for VS Code?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

When this question was first asked, neither the disassembly view nor the memory viewer were available.

In July of 2021, the [disassembly view](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/visual-studio-code-c-july-2021-update-disassembly-view-macro-expansion-and-windows-arm64-debugging/#disassembly-view) was released, which can be opened by clicking "Open Disassembly View" in the context menu of an editor. This is supported both by the generic C++ debugger debugger, and LLDB debugger has a "Toggle Disassembly" command which works quite well.

[image]

In February of 2022, the [memory view](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_64#_viewing-and-editing-binary-data) was released in VS Code, which can be accessed by hovering on a variable in the "Variables" view. Support for this only exists in the [LLDB C++ debugger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wN6aH.png) for now.

[image]

Comment: Ah that's a shame.  Suprising that it looks like no one had suggested this yet?  Thanks for opening.  I voted.  I also opened a request for an inline assembly view here: https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/293070-visual-studio-code/suggestions/15430521-assembly-view-for-c

Comment: I think the new place to up-vote is [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/941)

Comment: The disassembly view has been released a few months back. A memory viewer is tracked for the Nov 2021 milestone: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/126268

Comment: We shipped the memory viewer in 1.64 (Jan 2022). It's accessible via a "memory" icon when hovering on a variable. See: https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_64#_viewing-and-editing-binary-data

Comment: I knew vscode C++ debugging would be broken. That menu item isn't there.

Comment: How is the disassembly view themed in that example? I can't get that to work at all!

Answer (score 29):

At this time (Feb 2018), it seems that this feature still hasn't made it into VSCode. However it is possible to use the -exec command in the VSCode  Debug Console to run GDB commands. See https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp#_gdb-lldb-and-mi-commands-gdblldb

The GDB examine command "x" displays memory in various formats. So in the VSCode Debug Console

`-exec x/64b 0x74ae70`

will display 64 bytes in hexadecimal from 0x74ae70. See https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Memory.html for more details.

Comment: `-exec x/64xb 0x55555556aeb0` is enough for now. Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

At the time (Jun 2020), it seems that this feature still dosen't exist in VS code, [link (and maybe the answer you are looking for)](https://community.cypress.com/t5/ModusToolbox-General/Memory-dump-for-VSCODE/td-p/29028). However, we are coders and we can make our own features ;). I am fairly new to c++ so this code might not be any good, but it works and that is the important part. Code to memory view:

```
#include <iostream>
#include<cmath>

namespace mem
{
    std::string IntToHexa(int num)
    { 
        int values[2];
        int rest;
        for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            rest = num % 16;
            if(rest == 0 && num > 0)
            {
                values[i] = num/16;
            }else{
                values[i] = num % 16;
            }
            num -= values[i] * std::pow(16, i);

            if(values[i] > 9)
            {
                values[i] = 65 + values[i] - 10;
            }
        }

        std::string output;
        for(int i = 1; i > -1; i--)
        {
            if(values[i] > 10)
            {
                output += char(values[i]);
            }else{
                output += std::to_string(values[i]);
            }
        }
    return output;
    }

    template<typename POINTER>
    void MemView(POINTER pointer, int length = 10, int lines = 1)
    {
        unsigned char* ptr= (unsigned char*)pointer;
        for(int x = 0; x < lines; x++)
        {
            std::cout << (void*)ptr << "   ";
            for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
            {
                std::cout << IntToHexa((int)*ptr) << "  ";
                ptr++;
            }
            std::cout << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

So how do you use it some may wonder. Call the MemView function, `MemView(POINTER pointer, int length = 10, int lines = 1)`. The first parameter is a pointer (non function pointer). The next is how many bytes are shown in one row (set to 10 from start). The last parameter is how many lins (with so many byts set by the second parameter) should get printed (set to 1 from start). An example!

```
int main()
{
    int a = 10;
    int* ptr = &a;
    mem::MemView(ptr);
}
```

Output: `0x7ffee0a7a6ec   0A  00  00  00  00  A7  A7  2E  FE  7F`
The memory is written in hexadecimal which means that every pair is a byte. This is taken from the stack and is therefore in the reversed order. Because an int is 4 byts (0A  00  00  00) and it is in reversed order, you can see that (00  00  00 0A) has the value 10, which is the value of a. Another example!

```
int main()
{
    int a = 10;
    int* ptr = &a;
    mem::MemView(ptr, 4, 2);
}
```

The output:

```
0x7ffee4bec6ec   0A  00  00  00  
0x7ffee4bec6f0   00  C7  BE  E4
```

Now when the second parameter is 4, every row contains 4 bytes. There are 2 rows because the third parameter is set to 2. In the beginning of every row, a pointer to the first byte is showed. (The first byte in the next row is the following byte to the last byte in the first row). This program works will almost every pointer type, for example int, char, double ... However it dosen't work with function pointers (try and you will get an error).

Answer (score 8):

It is coming, with a preview feature in VSCode 1.59 (Jul. 2021)

> ### [Preview feature: Disassembly View](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/647426db05ae4048e5d09b235e65f7072889a8bb/release-notes/v1_59.md#preview-feature-disassembly-view)

> Thanks to a large code contribution by the C++ team, we are happy to include a preview of a Disassembly View in this milestone.
>
> The Disassembly view can be opened from an editor's context menu to show the disassembled source of the active stack frame, and it supports stepping through assembly instructions and setting breakpoints on individual instructions.
>
> The Disassembly view is only available in an active debug session and when the underlying debug extension supports it.
> As of today only the "C++" and "Mock Debug" extensions can feed the Disassembly view.
>
> [image: disassembly view in mock debug]
>
> From a technical perspective VS Code's implementation of the Disassembly view now supports four more features of the Debug Adapter Protocol:
>
> - the disassembly request for providing the disassembled source for a memory location,
> - the `instructionPointerReference` property on stack frames,
> - the granularity property on the stepping requests,
> - instruction breakpoints and the `setInstructionBreakpoints` request.

Comment: Hi may I as if I can do context highlight in the disassembly view??? Thank you very much~~

Comment: @Shore Not that I know of. That may be a good feature request to ask.