# Watching a memory adress of a data structure

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, pointers, memory, ram

Does anyone know how I can watch the memory address of a variable?

I use visual studio code for c++:
is there anyway I can watch the memory cells somehow when I have the hexadecimal address ?
I saw a video, where someone started a debugger an viewed the memory but maybe he used some extensions without going into detail.
I use mac.

Comment: Just add the expression `*(target_type*)(0xdeadbeef)` to the watch window

Comment: Are you sure you saw them using visual studio code or visual studio? They are different. [How to read the debug memory window in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12468194/how-to-read-the-debug-memory-window-in-visual-studio)

Comment: ... and append `,n` to watch `n` cells (`n` must be a constant).  Oh, my comment applies to VS, not VS Code.  Such a silly name, Microsoft.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38557168/does-vs-code-have-a-memory-viewer-and-or-a-disassembler-for-c-extension

Comment: You can find all the information you need about that in the [gdb manual](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/).

Answer (score -1):

I don't know about on the Mac but on the PC with VS it is Debug/Windows/Memory to see up to 4 blocks of raw memory for given base addresses.

Shortcut Ctrl-Alt-M 1 {2,3,4}
(that shortcut is almost certainly different on a Mac)

Comment: Is this for visual studio or visual studio code? In your answer you wrote *"PC with VS"*